# Check range for string value existing in other range (with wildcards at either end)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to search a range of cells for string values. Initially I had been hardcoding the criteria values into the formula and using COUNTIF, as below, which would return a value TRUE if the text string appeared anywhere in the search range.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:D1, "*VALUE1*") + COUNTIF(A1:D1, "*VALUE2*") + ... <0
```

However the list of criteria values I need to search has grown and hardcoding them is no longer viable. I know that COUNTIF criteria cannot reference a range, and needing wildcards also makes it tricky.

Anyone aware of any neat solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to put your `VALUE`s in a separate column ???

Comment: If a string contains **both** `VALUE1` and `VALUE2` your formula counts it **twice**, is that what you want ??

Comment: If a string contains both, all I need is a TRUE result. If a string is "xxxValue1" is in my search range I need it to register as TRUE also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing my hat in:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&F1:F2&"*",A1:D1,0)))
```

Depending on ones version this my need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try `SUMPRODUCT` with `SEARCH` functions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$2:$G$3,$A$1:$D$1)))>0
```

[image]

Comment: You got the parameters wrong > `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$2:$G$3,$A$1:$D$1)))`. And the only caveat when this is working is that if `D1` for example holds `XVALUE1VALUE2X` it will count twice. If OP compares it to `0` then there is no problem whatsoever and it should work just fine. +

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:D1,"*"&F1:F2&"*"))
```

Where `F1:F2` references your range with criteria. As with the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62215440/9758194), if both values occur in a single cell they will both be counted.

---

[image]

<sup>*N.B.:If you need to compare to 0 just use `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:D1,"*"&F1:F2&"*"))>0` to return `TRUE` or `FALSE`*</sup>